# Pandas to_excel- How to make it faster

Tags: performance, pandas, export-to-excel

I have a dataframe with 12,000 rows and 34 columns. It takes around 15 sec for pandas to write this to the excel. I read few discussion about to_excel function and one way to make it faster is by adding engine='xlsxwriter'. I use the following code.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('outputfile.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter')
res_df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Output_sheet')
```

Wondering if there is a way to make this work faster using dask or any other library?

dataframe.memory_usage() gave me the following output:

```
Index   80
col1    95528
col2    95528
col3    95528
col4    95528
col5    95528
col6    95528
col7    95528
col8    95528
col9    95528
col10   95528
col11   95528
col12   95528
col13   95528
col14   95528
col15   95528
col16   95528
col17   95528
col18   95528
col19   95528
col20   95528
col21   95528
col22   95528
col23   95528
col24   95528
col25   95528
col26   95528
col27   95528
col28   95528
col29   95528
col30   95528
col31   95528
col32   95528
col33   95528
col34   95528
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked how many bytes are those 12000 rows and 34 columns? Maybe it´s already at hard drive max speed

Comment: How long does it take to_csv ?

Comment: Hi Juvian, I added the output of the dataframe.memory_usgae(). Not quiet sure how to check the hard drive max speed. I use mac osx captain, 12 GB ram.

Comment: from what I read it seems that is the fastest you can go with pandas. pyexcelerate might be a bit faster, but using to_csv instead of to_excel with pandas improves speed quite a lot too

Comment: csv only takes 0.1 sec. I can not use csv as I am using the add_format() and conditional_format() from xlsxwriter. I was reading about dask that supports parallel computing but not sure if that supports writing to excel.

Comment: You can try xls instead of xlsx. You should check if pyexcelerate supports add_format and conditional_format, that´s the fastest library for writing to excel with python

Comment: Am I correct in saying that pyexcelerate is not supported by pandas?

Comment: yes, pandas has decided not to support pyexcelerate

Answer (score 16):

You can use [pyexcelerate](https://github.com/kz26/PyExcelerate) to get a much faster speed.

```
from pyexcelerate import Workbook

values = [res_df.columns] + list(res_df.values)
wb = Workbook()
wb.new_sheet('sheet name', data=values)
wb.save('outputfile.xlsx')
```

Comment: get error in last line : 'Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'z' referenced before assignmen' . P.S. : My dataframe has german characters.

Comment: You probably want to make sure that you're not using any variable before you've defined it.

Comment: This is not the case. Also there is no 'z'  variable in my program.